# how could I know how many layouts <include> a specific xml layout?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Suppose one layout file A includes another layout L, and I want to change the appearance of L in A. While I don't know if there're other files which also include L (if yes, leave them intact). What should I do to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the changes are in the L part and you only want them for A, I would replace `include` directive in `A` by the contents of `L`, then I would change A. How else?

Comment: yes, it works in this case, but if A, B ,C(which I don't know yet) all include L, and I want to change L for both A and B, what about this?.

Comment: grep where the L is included, how can you know something without knowing that something...

Comment: I simply don't want to the search work. Seems Intellij doesn't offer an quick approach , thanks anyway